# How to Scrape Multiple pages of one website with unchanging URL via Python?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have written following program to fetch data from all pages in this url, but its not working  I don't wanna use selenium, I have used same type of program to fetch data from other url but not working for this site
Please note than in this link pages are more than 10...

```
#PROGRAM 1:- 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os
import os.path
import datetime
import schedule      
import time

dt = str(datetime.date.today())
today = datetime.datetime.now()
#date_time = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y_%H_%M_%S")
date_time = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M")
print("date and time:",date_time)
file_name = 'BSE_Trades_' + date_time



save_path = r"C:\Users\ABCD"             
path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name+".csv")  

url = "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/TradenSettlement.aspx"

#headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/107.0.1418.52"}


dfs = pd.read_html(url)                                                                                                         
df = dfs[-2]

print(df)

count_row = df.shape[0]

data = {                             
    "__EVENTTARGET" : "",
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',  
    "__VIEWSTATE" : "",
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR": "",
    "__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED": "",
    "__EVENTVALIDATION": "",
    
       }

def updateData(response):
    global data
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    for i in data:
        try:
            data[i] = soup.find("input", id=i).get("value")
        except:
             pass
            
def main(url):
    global data
    targetString = "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridViewrcdsFC"
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={
                      'id': 'ContentPlaceHolder1_divCT1'}) [0]          

       # Print Table of First Page
        print(df)
        
        # get the last element of the last column, where the current page count is stored
      
        
        try: pageLength = int(df[0][count_row-1][-2])
        except: pageLength=int(df[0][count_row-2][-2])
        else: pageLength = int(df[0][count_row-1][-2])
               

        #try: pageLength = 22
        #except: pageLength = 0
        #else: pageLength = 22
        

        updateData(r)
                
        for pageNumber in range(1,pageLength):
            
            data["__EVENTTARGET"] = targetString #+str(pageNumber)
            data["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = "Page$" + str(pageNumber) #+str(pageNumber)
            data["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = "1BDEC9B0"
            
            r = req.post(url ,  data=data)
            
            _df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={
                          'id': 'ContentPlaceHolder1_divCT1'}) [0]          
            updateData(r)        
            df = df.append(_df)
            print (df)
      
        df.to_csv(path)

main("https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/TradenSettlement.aspx")
```

I HAVE WRITTEN PROGRAM IN OTHER AY AS WELL BUT IT IS ALSO NOT WORKING

---

```
#PROGRAM 2:- 
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
import datetime
#from datetime import datetime
import os
import os.path
import schedule      
import time


dt = str(datetime.date.today())
today = datetime.datetime.now()
date_time = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H.%M")
print("date and time:",date_time)
file_name = 'BSE_Data_' + date_time

save_path = r"C:\Users\XYZ"             
path = os.path.join(save_path, file_name+".csv")


endpoint = "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/TradenSettlement.aspx"

headers = {
    #"pageToken": "f06c7498-ac12-4def-95d2-f0fb903fff64",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/107.0.1418.52",
    #"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

#Actually Payload is not there in website though I have created it 

Payload = {
    "columnNames": [
        "Deal Type*(Brokered/Direct/IST)", "ISIN", "Listed/Unlisted security", "Issuer Name", "Coupon (%)",
        "Issue Description", "Traded Price in Rs", "Trade yield (%)", "Yield Type (YTC/YTP/YTM)#",
        "Yield Date", "Trade Value in Rs. Lacs (in face value term)", "Trade Date & Time", "Settlement Date", "Reported trade/Trade executed on RFQ platform",
        "Settlement Status^(Settled/Not Settled/Pending)", "Outside Yield Range",
    ]
}


response = requests.post(endpoint, data=json.dumps(Payload), headers=headers)

df = pd.DataFrame(response.json(), columns=Payload["columnNames"])

print(df)

df.to_csv(path, index=False)
```

PROGRAM 3 -- Here I have used Fire Command in event argument to increment the page till page size, still Its not working

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = {
    
    '__EVENTTARGET': "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridViewrcdsFC",
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'FireCommand:Page$1;PageSize;50',
    '__VIEWSTATE': "",
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '1BDEC9B0',
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED':"",
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':"moMXnWZxj4bZurveAGmOcL0nISClexUE9Z2uw4xpvBOm1MGb2OcWpeoR93Q2hSbZNPFrA13DJe+gToc4zKmJCrAz6mtps/4+Fuc55oo04aW5LAcfpXgJF4F9dtA80NIp6P5vueUYd7iUSQ1sGEnNlWQcghy//kGSS09BCEGrF6iX+zA/9P4X3Yjd8zLJRKyMbAYzKHPVaNNw1QovP7EsqwBhzHWN7R9IjuSvXBwbDC8Gtxkb8JmOx8Uh5ohoih8EmxSjHEjThJY79RbzkRBRzA==",
    
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        data['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
        data['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="__EVENTARGUMENT").get("value")
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        df = pd.read_html(r.content, attrs={
                          'id': 'ContentPlaceHolder1_GridViewrcdsFC'})[0]
        df.drop(df.columns[1], axis=1, inplace=True)
        print(df)
        #df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/TradenSettlement.aspx")
```

I want to scrape all pages from single url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments to your (now deleted) latest question, that page is optimally scraped with Selenium, to which you replied 'I don't know how to use Selenium'. It's really not difficult: here is one way of getting that data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time as t
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)

url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/markets/debt/TradenSettlement.aspx'
driver.get(url)
for x in range(2, 23):
    data = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="largetable"]'))).get_attribute('outerHTML')
    df = pd.read_html(data, header=0, skiprows=1)[0]
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//tr[@class="pgr"]'))).location_once_scrolled_into_view
    next_page = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//a[contains(@href, "Page${x}")]')))
    t.sleep(1)
    next_page.click()
    t.sleep(5)
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('some_business_stuff.csv')
```

Result in terminal (data is also saved as a csv file):

```
    Deal Type*(Brokered/Direct/IST) ISIN    Listed/Unlisted security    Issuer Name Coupon (%)  Issue Description   Traded Price in Rs  Trade yield (%) Yield Type (YTC/YTP/YTM)#   Yield Date  Trade Value in Rs. Lacs (in face value term)    Trade Date & Time   Settlement Date Reported trade/Trade executed on RFQ platform   Settlement Status^(Settled/Not Settled/Pending) Outside Yield Range
0   DIRECT  INE918T07129    UNLISTED    HERO WIND ENERGY PRIVATE LIMITED    0.0000  HERO WIND ENERGY PRIVATE LIMITED 9.05 NCD 21AP24 FVRS10LAC  99.9923 9.3600  YTM 4/21/2024 12:00:00 AM   199.98  11/23/2022 2:39:07 PM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
1   DIRECT  INE140A07690    LISTED  PIRAMAL ENTERPRISES LIMITED 0.0000  PIRAMAL ENTERPRISES LIMITED 101.3586    8.0000  YTM 9/20/2024 12:00:00 AM   304.08  11/23/2022 2:37:42 PM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
2   DIRECT  INE443L07166    UNLISTED    BELSTAR MICROFINANCE LIMITED    0.0000  BMLGSEC311024PVT    103.0175    9.3500  YTM 10/31/2024 12:00:00 AM  824.14  11/23/2022 2:34:43 PM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
3   DIRECT  INE342T07262    UNLISTED    Navi Finserv Limited    0.0000  NFLGSEC27324PVT 101.3728    8.9665  YTM 3/27/2024 12:00:00 AM   608.24  11/23/2022 2:33:19 PM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
4   DIRECT  INE033L07HY2    UNLISTED    TATA CAPITAL HOUSING FINANCE LIMITED    0.0000  TATA CAPITAL HOUSING FINANCE LIMITED SR G 8 NCD 03NV27 FVRS10LAC    100.2000    7.9400  YTM 11/3/2027 12:00:00 AM   501.00  11/23/2022 2:33:19 PM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
562 DIRECT  INE06E507066    UNLISTED    HELLA INFRA MARKET PRIVATE LIMITED  11.0000 HELLA INFRA MARKET PRIVATE LIMITED 11 NCD 22AG24 FVRS10000  100.8194    10.5000 YTM 8/22/2024 12:00:00 AM   57.67   11/23/2022 10:01:05 AM  23 Nov 2022 OTC SETTLED NaN
563 DIRECT  INE028A08224    LISTED  BANK OF BARODA  8.5000  BANK OF BARODA SR XIII 8.50 BD PERPETUAL FVRS10LAC  101.2500    7.9200  YTC 7/28/2025 12:00:00 AM   101.25  11/23/2022 9:55:38 AM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
564 DIRECT  INE583D07299    UNLISTED    UGRO CAPITAL LIMITED    10.1500 UGRO CAPITAL LIMITED SR I 10.15 NCD 28MR24 FVRS1000 100.7500    9.8700  YTM 3/26/2024 12:00:00 AM   10.08   11/23/2022 9:54:03 AM   23 Nov 2022 OTC PENDING NaN
565 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122 ...13141516171819202122
566 ... 13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
567 rows × 16 columns
```

Selenium setup is crome/chromedriver on a Linux system. See Selenium [documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) on how to write a workable setup on your own system, and from the code above, just mind the imports, and the code after defining the driver.